# Synonymize [google-form-quiz] to [google-forms]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[google-form-quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-form-quiz)  excerpts and wiki states it's about a specific feature of [google-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-forms). This minor feature is [documented here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7032287).

Since it's inception in 2017, [google-form-quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-form-quiz) only has 64 questions compared to 2000+ questions on the main tag. **All** of it needs to be  tagged with the parent tag [google-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-forms) as well. The tag currently has 7 watchers against 188 watchers on the parent.

This tag is not needed and it is unnecessarily segregating questions about Google forms.
Propose synonimizing [google-form-quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-form-quiz) to [google-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-forms).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was already a synonym proposed for the same, so I approved it. The tags are now synonyms, that is:

[google-form-quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-form-quiz) (× 64) → [google-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-forms) (× 2225)

And as usual, I'll merge the tags after a few days, just in case there are any issues with the synonym

Comment: Great! Thank you! But Would it be better left as a synonym, in case some one tries to recreate it again?